# Iteration in Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am looking to achieve some iteration in a Data Fusion pipeline.

My pipeline has 2 BQ Execute steps.
The first BQ Execute queries the following "Control_Table" in BigQuery:

| System_Name | Start_Data | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| system_a | 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/31 |
| system_b | 2022/01/01 | 2023/01/31 |
| system_c | 2021/10/01 | 2023/01/31 |

Within this plugin, I have enabled the "Set rows as Arguments" option that sets these values as parameters.

I need the second BQ Execute to run the following multiple times, once for each of the rows in the control table. For example, a simple SQL like this:

`SELECT col_a, col_b from dw_table  WHERE system_name = ${system_name} and transaction_date between ${start_date} and ${end_date};`

The idea is to append those results to a temp table.
How do I implement this functionality?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements by adding more details?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the results of a previous stage is not supported in Cloud Data Fusion.

If might be possible to implement something like this using the BigQuery procedural language https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language